# Cocos2d v3 CCButton with label using CCLabelBMFont

Tags: button, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a CCButton named "Start" in cocos2d v3 using CCLableBMFont label as the button image. But I can't seem to get the label to be in the CCButton in v3.
Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a utility function I added to my current project that does just that:

```
+(CCButton *)smallButtonWithLabel:(NSString *)button_label;
```

And the implementation:

```
+(CCButton *)smallButtonWithLabel:(NSString *)button_label
{
        CCButton *button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:nil spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"dlg-sml-btn-bg-s.png"] highlightedSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"dlg-sml-btn-bg-t.png"] disabledSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"dlg-sml-btn-bg-s.png"]];
        [button setBackgroundOpacity:0.5 forState:CCControlStateDisabled];

        CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:button_label fntFile:SS_FONT_48_24_MULTI width:button.contentSize.width alignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter];
        label.position = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
        label.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
        [button addChild:label];

        return button;
    }
```

You can modify it a little bit to fit your needs.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can apply a `CCLableBMFont` to a CCButton. Looking at the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCButton.html), the only options available are:

```
+ (id)buttonWithTitle:(NSString *)title fontName:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)size
```

or

```
+ (id)buttonWithTitle:(NSString *)title spriteFrame:(CCSpriteFrame *)spriteFrame
```

and a couple variations of these two. So I think you will have to settle with a sprite or a label with a TTF font as the button background.

Comment: Yes, at this time there is no out of the box solution, you are correct. What I do is just place a `CCButton` with no string on it and center a `BMFont` label on it. Still is pretty hacky but it gets the job done.